# Can not find the right WCF endpoint configuration

Tags: web-services, wcf, endpoint

I created service that take the data from android and save them into SQL. I am using IIS 7

My code:

```
namespace WcfService_SuiviColis
{
    // REMARQUE : vous pouvez utiliser la commande Renommer du menu Refactoriser pour changer le nom d'interface "IService1" à la fois dans le code et le fichier de configuration.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,  BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,  UriTemplate = "SaveData")]
        void SaveData(Pers_Ordre_NET oData);      
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Pers_Ordre_NET
    {
        [DataMember]
        string _CodeClient;
        public string CodeClient
        {
            get { return _CodeClient; }
            set { _CodeClient = value; }
        }

       [DataMember]
        string _CodeDest;
        public string CodeDest
        {
            get { return _CodeDest; }
            set { _CodeDest = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        string _NoOrdre;
        public string NoOrdre
        {
            get { return _NoOrdre; }
            set { _NoOrdre = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        string _DateTampon;
        public string DateTampon
        {
            get { return _DateTampon; }
            set { _DateTampon = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        string _GeoPos;
        public string GeoPos
        {
            get { return _GeoPos; }
            set { _GeoPos = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        string _StsOrdre;
        public string StsOrdre
        {
            get { return _StsOrdre; }
            set { _StsOrdre = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        string _Camion;
        public string Camion
        {
            get { return _Camion; }
            set { _Camion = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

and `service.svc.cs`:

```
namespace WcfService_SuiviColis
{
    // REMARQUE : vous pouvez utiliser la commande Renommer du menu Refactoriser pour changer le nom de classe "Service1" dans le code, le fichier svc et le fichier de configuration.
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void SaveData(Pers_Ordre_NET oOrdre)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
                {
                    var connectedConnection = connectionWrapper.GetConnected();
                    string sql_Adding = "INSERT INTO [SUIVI_ORDRE]"+
                                          " ([CODE_CLIENT] ,[CODE_DEST],[NO_ORDRE],[DATE_TAMPON],[GPS_POS],[STATUS_ORDRE],CAMION)"+
                                    "VALUES (@CODE_CLIENT,@CODE_DEST,@NO_ORDRE,@DATE_TAMPON,@GPS_POS,@STATUS_ORDRE,@CAMION)";
                    SqlCommand comm_Insrt = new SqlCommand(sql_Adding, connectionWrapper.conn);
                    comm_Insrt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE_CLIENT", oOrdre.CodeClient);
                    comm_Insrt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE_DEST", oOrdre.CodeDest);
                    comm_Insrt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO_ORDRE", oOrdre.NoOrdre);
                    comm_Insrt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_TAMPON", oOrdre.DateTampon);
                    comm_Insrt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GPS_POS", oOrdre.GeoPos);
                    comm_Insrt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS_ORDRE", oOrdre.StsOrdre);
                    comm_Insrt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAMION", oOrdre.Camion);
                    comm_Insrt.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                throw new Exception(excThrown.Message);
            }
        }    
    }   
}
```

and `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
    <services>          
        <service name="WcfService_SuiviColis.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint 
                address="SaveData" 
                behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="WcfService_SuiviColis.IService1"  />
        </service>
    </services>  
    <behaviors> 
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">       
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="httpBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
     <security>
         <requestFiltering>
             <verbs>
                 <add verb="POST" allowed="true"/>
             </verbs>
             <fileExtensions>
                 <add fileExtension=".svc" allowed="true"/>
             </fileExtensions>
         </requestFiltering>
     </security>

     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

I can not find the right configuration for the endpoint.

When I write like this:

```
<endpoint 
    address="SaveData" behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior" 
    binding="webHttpBinding" 
    contract="WcfService_SuiviColis.IService1" />
```

I got endpoint not found

When I write it like this:

```
<endpoint 
    address="" behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
    binding="webHttpBinding" 
    contract="WcfService_SuiviColis.IService1"  />
```

I got method not allowed

When I write like this:

```
<endpoint 
    address="" 
    binding="basicHttpBinding"   
    contract="WcfService_SuiviColis.IService1"  />
```

I got error 415, type mismatch because I want to receive JSON but in fiddler I got html

I put also `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"`

When I put

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

I got error 400 page not found

I call my method like this:

```
http://mydomain:4004/Code/WcfService_SuiviColis/WcfService_SuiviColis/Service1.svc/SaveData
```

**EDITED**
i think the correct endpoint :

```
<endpoint 
    address="" behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
    binding="webHttpBinding" 
    contract="WcfService_SuiviColis.IService1"  />
```

but with this endpoint i got error 405, mmethode not allowed. is posible that IIS 7 not allowed POST (receive the data from ANDROID to SERVER) ?
because i have created another wcf programm with GET (send the data from SERVER to ANDROID) it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the address of the endpoint you are defining is not valid. It should contain the full address of the machine where the service is located along with the port number

```
<endpoint address ="http://mydomain:4004/...../>
```

Comment: thanks for responding, i did but i got erro 500 because <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">, and then i change it into false, but i got erro 400 page not found

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using IIS, the web URL to use is basically defined by IIS: your server name, name of the virtual directory, path and location of the `*.svc` file.

```
http://YourWebServer/VirtualDirectory/Path/service.svc
```

Then, you might have an additional, relative address in your endpoint definition, so if you use

```
<endpoint 
    address="SaveData" behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior" 
    binding="webHttpBinding" 
    contract="WcfService_SuiviColis.IService1" />
```

then the complete URL would be:

```
http://YourWebServer/VirtualDirectory/Path/service.svc/SaveData
```

I'm not sure if you might need to add another `/SaveData` to that URL since you've defined this as your `UriTemplate` on the service contract:

```
http://YourWebServer/VirtualDirectory/Path/service.svc/SaveData/SaveData
                                                       ++++++++ ********
                                                          |         |
                                             relative address       |
                                             from endpoint          |
                                                                    |
                                          UriTemplate from your service contract
```

Endpoint not found usually means you're using a wrong URL to try and access your service.